# jQuery stop (window).scrollTop function

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, window, scrolltop

I have an if else statement where it adds a class if the scroll is over 50px. Is there a way I can cancel out this entire function if I were to click a button?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>50){
        $('.scroller').addClass('fixedposition');
    } else {
        $('.scroller').removeClass('fixedposition');
    }
});
```

I have that same .scroller class on multiple places on the page so I would like to turn it off in certain events.

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSXCz/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should disable any action that is attached to scrolling (solution independent from library that you are using)

```
$('body').on({
'mousewheel': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

Other (more appropriate) solution would be to unbind scroll assuming you are using Jquery scroll

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

last one would be to

```
$('button')
    .on('click', function () {
        $('.scroller')
            .toggleClass('scroller-enabled');
})
```

and based on `scroller-enabled` class enable or disable functionality.

Comment: `$(window).unbind('scroll');` is exactly what I was looking for. I also learned `.bind` would let me reenable the scroll; Thanks for the help!